# I want to select last row from the table. Please have look at the tables structure below

Tags: phpmyadmin

it looks like:

**table 1**

```
id   eid

1    49

2    49

3    50

4    51

5    50

6    52

7    53
```

........ and so on

and my **2nd table** structure is as follow.(id is same as above)

```
id    status

1     ok

2     v.good

3     fine

4     ok     

5     good

6     fine

7     v.good
```

I want the latest status of all eid's means the current status of the 49 v.good and 50 good and so on....

Please help me in write it down this query.

thnks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that this is done in mysql. if this is the case then something like

```
select * from yourtable where eid=yourvalue order by eid desc limit 1;
```

Comment: I want status form the 2nd table and eid I am getting from the another query.

Comment: actually I want to plot a graph between ok and v.good. fine comes in ok category and good comes in v.good category so basically graph will have (ok,fine) and (good,v.good). and this graph is based on the latest status. so eid 49 wont come in ok category instead it will come in v.good category. This information may help you in writing down the query